# using system mongodb for multiple docker containers?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, dockerfile

I am very new to Docker and I'm struggling with a configuration. My current configuration is that I have multiple Node/Express microservices on my local system which are using `nodemon`. All of these connect to mongodb running on `mongodb://localhost:27017/localv2`.

I'm trying to dockerize all my microservices. The issue is that they are not able to connect to mongodb on `localhost:27017`. I have 2 questions:

1. Why are they not able to connect to localhost:27017?
2. How to make them connect to the current running mongodb in my system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 & 2. When you build a docker container, it creates VLAN for docker container with ip address gateway is : `172.17.42.1`, so docker container would connect to mongo, it should be : `mongodb://172.17.42.1:27017/localv2`

Comment: Cool. I get this point. But I'm running multiple microservices. If there is a docker container for each of them, there there will be a different mogodb URL for each of them. I want a single database. Can you please point me to the right direction of how to achieve this?

Comment: Using only 1 URL above for multiple docker containers. Because `172.17.42.1` is gateway ip address for all docker containers.

Comment: I got this to work by using a combination of your and Guillaume Simonneau's answer below. One more issue though: What to do if my mongodb is running remotely, like on modulus? My mongo connection string is something like: `mongodb://uname:password@jello.modulusmongo.net:27017/db123`. When I run my container, it gives error: `MongoError: failed to connect to server [jello.modulusmongo.net:27017] on first connect`.

Comment: `[jello.modulusmongo.net:27017]` means port 27017 hasn't opened on modulus, check it.

Comment: It is open. The same thing works when I run my app using normal `node` command. It is not working from inside docker container.

Comment: It's ok. The modulus connections are blocked in the place I work. That is why it wasn't able to connect to it. My bad. Sorry about this.

Comment: Ah! Really sorry about it. Got caught up in some stuff for the past few days.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```

```
version: '2'
services:

  mongod:
    image: khezen/mongo:3.4
    volumes:
      - /data/mongo/mongod1:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    network_mode: bridge
    restart: unless-stopped

  helloworld:
    build: ./
    links: 
      - mongod:database
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    network_mode: bridge
    restart: unless-stopped
```

```

helloworld will resolve `datatabase` as the ip address of `mongod`

Answer (score 0):

first,
-you need to find docker container ip addres by,
 docker inspect container_id 
-the field is like  "IPAddress": "172.17.0.7"

second,
-you neeed to start mongod on your local machine
-you need to use mongochef(mongo browser)
-from mongo browser you need to connect mongo client as
localhost:27017 instead of this use container-ip:27017
and connect to mongodb instance